# How do I convert a for loop to a vector and write that to a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, append

I have created a for loop which extracts all my files from my path and prints the same. I wanted to put this entire functions output into a dataframe and write it to a csv. I know we can do this in R by creating a vector but how do we do it in python?

```
import pandas
import glob

for filepath in glob.iglob('*.csv'):
    fl = pandas.read_csv(filepath);
    fl.insert(25,'city',filepath)
    print(fl.groupby('city').mean())
```

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Comment: fl is already a dataframe. Here's the documentation to write a dataframe to a CSV: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `f1` variable is already a DataFrame. To output it into a csv file on the same directory just use the `to_csv` methond from pandas.DataFrame.

```
f1.to_csv('filename.csv')
```